# можно ли из idle вывести комментарий в shell?

Tags: python

я прокомментировал ,то что я написал в IDLE, и хочу увидеть комментарий в shell. ВОзможно ли это?

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 0):

print( primer.**doc** ) выводит все строки документации которые включает эта функция.
если коменты сделать строками документации через '''   ''', в выводе будет текст этих строк. **doc** двойной underscor